# Get only specific fields when fetching data using Ecto in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to return some JSON Data in one of my API Calls in Phoenix. I'm fetching all records of `Subject` and sending them but `Ecto` returns some extra fields that I do not want.

What can I do to:

- Get only specific attributes (E.g. only `id` and `name`)
- Not get unnecessary fields in my response (such as `__meta__` and `__owner__`)

---

This is my `Controller`:

```
# Controller
def index(conn, _) do
    subjects = Subject |> Repo.all
    conn |> render subjects: subjects
end
```

This is my `View`:

```
# View
def render("index.json", %{subjects: subjects}) do
    subjects
end
```

This is my response:

```
[
    {
        "teachers": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "teachers",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-06-20T15:32:20Z",
        "topics": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "topics",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "name": "Physics",
        "inserted_at": "2015-06-20T15:32:20Z",
        "id": 1,
        "__meta__": {
            "state": "loaded",
            "source": "subjects"
        }
    },
    {
        "teachers": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "teachers",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-06-20T15:37:59Z",
        "topics": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "topics",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "name": "Chemistry",
        "inserted_at": "2015-06-20T15:37:59Z",
        "id": 2,
        "__meta__": {
            "state": "loaded",
            "source": "subjects"
        }
    },
    {
        "teachers": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "teachers",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-06-20T15:38:41Z",
        "topics": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "topics",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "name": "Mathematics",
        "inserted_at": "2015-06-20T15:38:41Z",
        "id": 3,
        "__meta__": {
            "state": "loaded",
            "source": "subjects"
        }
    },
    {
        "teachers": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "teachers",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "updated_at": "2015-06-22T15:40:17Z",
        "topics": {
            "__owner__": "Elixir.MyApp.Subject",
            "__field__": "topics",
            "__cardinality__": "many"
        },
        "name": "Biology",
        "inserted_at": "2015-06-22T15:40:17Z",
        "id": 4,
        "__meta__": {
            "state": "loaded",
            "source": "subjects"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your view to:

```
def render("index.json", %{subjects: subjects}) do
  Enum.map(subjects, &Map.take(&1, [:id, :name]))
end
```

Additionally, you can also ask Ecto to return a subset of fields by changing your controller to:

```
def index(conn, _) do
  subjects = from(s in Subject, select: %{id: s.id, name: s.name}) |> Repo.all
  conn |> render subjects: subjects
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand how to select specific fields, but what if I want to reject a specific field and get everything else. For example, if I don't want `teachers` and `topics` in the above example.

Comment: Change `Map.take/2` to `Map.drop/2`. You can find all map functions at http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/.